# Using UIImage in FBDialogs

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ios7, fbdialogs

I am developing an app which has an option to share a photo via Facebook.
My photo is UIImage instance (and not URL, I don't need it to be a link).

Using the iOS integrated dialog, I am able to post an image to my wall, but the problem is that it appears "Shared via iOS" (which is logical, because it was shared using the iOS integrated dialog box).

I am interested it to appear "Shared via [my_app_name]", but I do not see a way to upload an UIImage using FBDialogs.

What I tried is to upload the photo to user's photos and then use the result I get from the FBRequestConnection, but I see there only a link to the picture.

Can someone please help?

Thanks!